# Commits in concurrent transactions

Tags: database, concurrency, commit

Concurrent transaction execution.

```
 T1         T2 
================= 
           R(A)

R(A)       
A=A+100      
W(A)       
           A=A+200
           W(A)
           commit

commit
```

Here Initially A=100. what will be the value of A after the final commit?
Note: The above schedule of transactions executes concurrently (Inter-leaved) as shown.

Comment: What isolation level are you using? eg http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.3.0/devguide/cdevconcepts15366.html

Comment: I can't exactly tell you, as I'm just getting started. But dirty reads are allowed if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Having thought about it, given the way you've laid it out, it depends on the locking strategy as much as anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities depending on the locking strategy:

1. With optimistic locking, T2 will commit a value of 300 to the DB and T1 will get an optimistic locking exception
2. With row or table level locking and assuming T2 gets the lock first then A=400. This is because T2 gets a lock first and T1 will then block until T2 has finished. T2 therefore commits A=300. T1 then reads this value and commits A=400. Obviously in this case, the operations aren't interleaved as shown.

There is a 3rd possibility where T1 could get the lock first. In this case, T1 can't commit after T2 so it isn't really possible based on your diagram.